# Subsample data frame by time, keep top of the second value

Tags: r, dataframe, sample, posixct

I have a data frame containing timestamps with fractional seconds.  There is more than one row per second, and I want to filter down to a single row.  I want to extract the values at or immediately before the top of each second.

Here is an example of the data:

```
 > head(sg1, 13)
                      time  count
1  2013-02-25 15:55:35.941      0
2  2013-02-25 15:55:36.042   8263
3  2013-02-25 15:55:36.144 147536
4  2013-02-25 15:55:36.243 165041
5  2013-02-25 15:55:36.342 126064
6  2013-02-25 15:55:36.441 100275
7  2013-02-25 15:55:36.542 101944
8  2013-02-25 15:55:36.647 108880
9  2013-02-25 15:55:36.742  86690
10 2013-02-25 15:55:36.842  74476
11 2013-02-25 15:55:36.941  76285
12 2013-02-25 15:55:37.042  79145
13 2013-02-25 15:55:37.141  84434
```

Of these, I want to select rows 1 and 11.

```
> dput(head(sg1, 13))
structure(list(time = structure(c(1361807735.942, 1361807736.042, 
1361807736.145, 1361807736.244, 1361807736.343, 1361807736.442, 
1361807736.542, 1361807736.647, 1361807736.742, 1361807736.842, 
1361807736.942, 1361807737.042, 1361807737.142), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "GMT"), count = c(0L, 8263L, 147536L, 165041L, 
126064L, 100275L, 101944L, 108880L, 86690L, 74476L, 76285L, 79145L, 
84434L)), .Names = c("time", "count"), row.names = c(NA, 13L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 4):

The hard part is that you want

> the values at or immediately before the top of each second.

So rounding down the time and taking the largest one doesn't quite work because if there is one at the top of the second, it gets put into the wrong group. This approach handles that case correctly.

```
library("lubridate")
library("plyr")
ddply(sg1, .(ceiling_date(time, unit="second")), function(DF) {
  DF[which.max(DF$time - ceiling_date(DF$time)),]
})[,-1]
```

which gives

```
                 time count
1 2013-02-25 15:55:35     0
2 2013-02-25 15:55:36 76285
3 2013-02-25 15:55:37 84434
```

And to show that this works with a round second, add one to the data set.

```
sg2 <- rbind(sg1, 
structure(list(time=structure(1361807737, class=c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), 
tzone="GMT"), count=c(34567L)), .Names = c("time", "count"), row.names=c(NA,1L),
class="data.frame"))
sg2 <- sg2[order(sg2$time),]

ddply(sg2, .(ceiling_date(time, unit="second")), function(DF) {
  DF[which.max(DF$time - ceiling_date(DF$time)),]
})[,-1]
```

which now returns the new row for the "previous" second.

```
                 time count
1 2013-02-25 15:55:35     0
2 2013-02-25 15:55:37 34567
3 2013-02-25 15:55:37 84434
```

Comment: Nice catch about "the values at or immediately before the top of each second". I'd missed that.

Answer (score 3):

```
tapply(rownames(sg1), format(sg1$time, "%Y-%m-%d %M:%S"), tail, 1)
2013-02-25 55:35 2013-02-25 55:36 2013-02-25 55:37 
             "1"             "11"             "13"
```

I doubt I need to explain this to you, Matthew. If you wanted numeric class, you could use `1:nrow(sg1)` instead of rownames. (Oh, after posting I see you remembered `tail`.)

Since you now appear to want the entire rows you use this as an index into sg1:

```
> sg1[ tapply(rownames(sg1), format(sg1$time, "%Y-%m-%d %M:%S"), tail, 1) , ]
                  time count
1  2013-02-25 15:55:35     0
11 2013-02-25 15:55:36 76285
13 2013-02-25 15:55:37 84434
```

... or could rbind the split dfrms:

```
> do.call(rbind, lapply(split(sg1, format(sg1$time, "%Y-%m-%d %M:%S")), tail, 1) )
                                time count
2013-02-25 55:35 2013-02-25 15:55:35     0
2013-02-25 55:36 2013-02-25 15:55:36 76285
2013-02-25 55:37 2013-02-25 15:55:37 84434
```

... arguably more "standard R".

Comment: `tail` seems dangerous, as it could silently give wrong results for data that are not completely time-ordered.

Answer (score 1):

There's an extra row in there because this just grabs the `max(time)` within each second, but:

```
library(lubridate)
df$second = floor(second(df$time))

library(plyr)
top_seconds = ddply(
  df,
  .(second),
  function(df_part) {
    return(df_part[df_part$time == max(df_part$time), ])
  })
```

Comment: An extra row is of no concern.  This won't take top of the second if it is exactly .000, but in this case I can fix that by taking the operation on df$time-.001 (the data is in millisecond resolution).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a base R solution:

```
do.call(rbind, by(data = sg1, 
                  INDICES = as.numeric(sg1$time) %/% 1,
                  FUN = function(X) {
                      X[which.max(as.numeric(X$time) %% 1), ]
                  }))
#                                      time count
# 2013-02-25-:55:35 2013-02-25 15:55:35.941     0
# 2013-02-25-:55:36 2013-02-25 15:55:36.941 76285
# 2013-02-25-:55:37 2013-02-25 15:55:37.141 84434
```

---

If, as Brian Diggs surmises, you'd like to include 15:55:36.941 and 15:55:37.000 in the same second, keeping the latter if they're both present, try this:

```
do.call(rbind, by(data = sg2, 
                  INDICES = ceiling(as.numeric(sg2$time)),
                  FUN = function(X) {
                      X[which.max(as.numeric(X$time) %% -1), ]
                  }))
```

Comment: I would not have thought to code `%% 1` before reading this (and subsequently googling "r fractional part of number").

Comment: @MatthewLundberg -- Well then have a look at the just-edited version. `%/%` is just as nice as its counterpart ;)

Answer (score 1):

Marius gives me the clue I needed.  Here's a solution in base:

```
do.call(rbind, unname(by(sg1, floor(as.numeric(sg1$time)), FUN=tail, 1)))
                      time count
1  2013-02-25 15:55:35.941     0
11 2013-02-25 15:55:36.941 76285
13 2013-02-25 15:55:37.141 84434
```

Answer (score 1):

Just another `base` solution

```
sg1[sg1$time %in% aggregate(sg1$time, 
                            by = list(ceiling(as.numeric(sg1$time))), 
                            FUN = max)$x, ]
##                   time count
## 1  2013-02-25 15:55:35     0
## 11 2013-02-25 15:55:36 76285
## 13 2013-02-25 15:55:37 84434
```